# send bulk messages to my telegram bot subscribers with chat.id

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to send messages with my telegram bot to subscribers.

I already store all chat ids from my subscribers in TXT file every chat id in 1 line.
now I need help to access this file and make send.messages go throw all chat ids without going over the API 30 messages per second.

my script works on python

please help :[

Answer (score 0):

Due to this Issue
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1183
I think it is not possible to send a message to multiple chat_ids with one send_message command.